# AutoRender = False doesn't work in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

Been trying to figure this out for hours but can't get it to work!

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/build-a-shopping-cart-with-cakephp-and-jquery-part-1) to implement a simple shopping cart feature using Ajax and CakePHP

In the CartsController, we have to set: $this->autoRender = false; since the Ajax call doesn't need to load the 'ADD' view. However, when I click the 'Add to Cart' button, it returns a blank page with the correct quantity number. If I go back a page and refresh it, then I can see the item has been added to the cart.

How do I disable this blank page (with the qty) from loading and have Ajax just update the cart counter?

CakePHP:

```
public function add() {
$this->autoRender = false;

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Cart->addProduct($this->request->data['Cart']['product_id']);
}

echo $this->Cart->getCount();
}
```

FYI:

- addProduct just loops through an array in the session and increments the variable (if found) or adds to the array (if not found)
- getCount just returns the count of the items in the array.

Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add-form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var tis = $(this);
            $.post(tis.attr('action'),tis.serialize(),function(data){
                $('#cart-counter').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

FYI, I'm making this reference to jQuery in my default.ctp:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you tried adding a `return;` after the echo in the action?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work either :(

Comment: put return false in the form submit function, since the form submit will redirect to the page

Comment: <?php echo $this->Form->create('Cart',array('id'=>'add-form','url'=>array(                 'controller'=>'carts','action'=>'add'),                    'default'=>'false'));?>

Like that? It doesn't work either

Comment: Are you sure the form id is correct? The page shouldn't refresh after submitting the form.

Comment: To reinforce @DineshKumarDJ suggestion, in Form create add default option to false (in case you haven't done so already) `$this->Form->create('Model', array('default' => false))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.

@CatalinMunteanu - Yes, I've just doubled checked and it's called 'add-form' in every part.

DineshKumarDJ and Nunser - I've just added the Default = false, now nothing happens. A blank page doesn't come up but the cart is left untouched too!

Comment: Could you show us the code used for creating for Form?

Comment: Are you adding jQuery before your JS code? Because if it's after, javascript won't recognize the `$` variable and thus not doing any ajax call

Comment: THANK YOU EAGLE!! This was it! I started with the default Bootstrap template which has the jQuery at the end of the default.ctp and I was making the call in one of the views! Why would Bootstrap include the jQuery plugin at the end of the file?! I'd imagine such Ajax calls using the `$` are quite common :S

But thank you!!!

Comment: Wow, such a simple mishap, hahaha. Often happens, don't worry. Then I'll change my answer to give a proper solution, as it seems Cake json serialization wasn't the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that jQuery is added before your custom javascript code. If not, the `$` variable won't be loaded and your ajax call won't execute at all.

Comment: It didn't make a difference :(

Comment: If I disable the autoRender, I get:

Missing View
Error: The view for CartsController::add() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: [path]\app\View\Carts\add.ctp

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_view.ctp

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie at CakePHP, so just to confirm I just had to add the following above my functions in the CartsController:

var $components = array('RequestHandler');

That doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmm.. okay, it adds the item to the cart but I still get the error I mentioned in my previous comment; about the missing controller. Nah, no Javascript errors that prompt up :S

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var tis = $(this);
        $.post(tis.attr('action'),tis.serialize(),function(data){
            $('#cart-counter').text(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

put return false in the form submit function, since the form submit will redirect to the page, you have to prevent the original form submit, since you post request the action.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should prevent submitting the form the standard way

Comment: That's what I thought too. I did try it however, it doesn't make a difference!