# Writing to Session in CakePHP doesn't Save

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

Just solved one issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294833/autorender-false-doesnt-work-in-cakephp), now another...

As mentioned before, I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/build-a-shopping-cart-with-cakephp-and-jquery-part-1) to create a simple shopping cart using CakePHP, Ajax and Bootstrap.

I've got it working for the most part except **it appears though that the items added to the cart aren't saved.** I can add an item, move around the website and even change it's quantity and it remains as is - however, when I try to add another item - the second item just completely overwrites the first item.

This is the CakePHP Cart Model function that runs when adding an item:

```
public function addProduct($productId) {
        $allProducts = $this->read();
        if (null!=$allProducts) {
            if (array_key_exists($productId, $allProducts)) {
                $allProducts[$productId]++;
            } else {
                $allProducts[$productId] = 1;
            }
        } else {
            $allProducts[$productId] = 1;
        }

        $this->saveProduct($allProducts);
    }


public function saveProduct($data) {
        return CakeSession::write('cart',$data);
}
```

That's called by the `add` Function in the Controller:

```
 public function add() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Cart->addProduct($this->request->data['Cart']['product_id']);
        }
        echo $this->Cart->getCount();
    }
```

My Cart Model looks like this at the start:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

class Cart extends AppModel {....}
```

Comment: what's `$this->read()`?

Comment: any reason why you are using `CakeSession` instead of [Session Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html)?

Comment: Looks like a logic error. Unless you've redefined `$this->read()` - when you call it you'll get the data for _one_ item returned. You then overwrite the session data with that one item's data. @Nunser there's no session component in a model; there is a static session interface anywhere though.

Comment: To be honest, I'm still learning so I'm not sure what it exactly does... It's straight off the tutorial [here](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/build-a-shopping-cart-with-cakephp-and-jquery-part-2) and it says it works for them!

@AD7six - how would I redefine it to read them all instead of just one?

Comment: I solved it! It was a typo on the tutorial. It should've been readProduct() not just read(), since later on there is this function:

`public function readProduct() {return CakeSession::read('cart');}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**: There is a typo in the tutorial, it should be `readProduct()` not `read()` at the start of the `addProduct` function.